# how to find the vertical distance from top in px of an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I find the vertical distance from the top of the page to where the element exist in the DOM using javascript/jQuery?

I've something like

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li class="test">one</li>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

For example here, I want to find the vertical distance from top of the page to the `li#test` element.

I tried `.scrollTop()` but it always comes as 0!

Comment: is this what your looking for? var position = $('li#test').position();
alert(position.top);

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the distance between an element and the top of the document:

```
$("li.test").offset().top
```

Answer (score 106):

Rob W's answer is correct - that will give you the offset from the top of the full page.

If you want to get the offset from the top of the viewable screen, you should do this:

```
var viewableOffset = $("#li.test").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: Haha thanks.  SO's always been a useful hit on Google searches, and I was bored and figured I'd answer some questions.  I'm mostly trolling around here while waiting for an answer on SO's sister site, ServerFault.  I'm a longtime programmer and newbie admin. :)

Comment: This is an excellent bit of code if you're controlling position: fixed elements!

Comment: Brilliant solution. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know `.offset()` get the distance between the current scroll position and the top of the document.

You need to use this: `$("li.test").position().top`

Comment: relative to the offsetParent, which may not be the parent div

Answer (score 0):

Use $(element).offset().top and add height of existing fixed elements on the page to it to make it more accurate.